# Which effect/filter is used in this photo?

Tags: effect

Center of the image is zoomed in while edges and corners are zoomed out. How to apply this effect? Which application to use?

[image]

Comment: The "application" is an understanding of perspective and how it is influenced by camera subject distance.

Comment: Why do you think the center of the image is zoomed in? It is not. This is a wide-angle photo taken with a [fisheye lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisheye_lens). This is what allows such a wide angle to be captured.

Comment: "fisheye lens" what I was looking for. I will select it if you post it as an answer

Comment: Please use a descriptive title. Can you imagine how many did questions could share this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no special effect or filter recognizable.

The human eye has about f = 45-50 mm; wide-angle lenses (f < 45 mm) have the result that objects very near to the camera look unproportionally larger than they look to the naked eye; the smaller f gets, the more obvious the distortion. Note that tele lenses (f > 50 mm) have the opposite result; everything seems to be about equally distant, 'flattened out'.

This shot is probably done with a 22 or 18 mm, and if you go even further down, you get such a strong and obvious distortion that it has its own name, *'fisheye'*.